# How to Display time in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have added these code to display the selected date from a text box.

```
var date_arr = new Array( "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

var avd_dateValue = document.getElementById("Available_Date").value;
var avd_date = avd_dateValue.split('-'); 
var date2 = new Date (avd_date[2], date_arr.indexOf(avd_date[1]),avd_date[0]);
```

when i need to display the time, i used

```
alert(date2);
```

It's displaying like this

```
Fri Dec 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

but Current time is not been displayed. As i am new to this platform i am not getting the actual issue behind it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours();
    var m = date.getMinutes();
    var s = date.getSeconds();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var currentdate = date.getDate();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

     var time = day+" "+month+" "+currentdate+" "+year+" "+h+":"+m+":"+s
```

For more details you can refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

> but Current time is not been displayed

When you [create a Date object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) using two or more values, it is assumed that you are supplying all the values (year, month, day, hour, minute, second and millisecond). If you don't supply all of them, the missing values are set to zero.

If you want to create a Date for a particular date that has the current time, then create a Date for now and set the year, month and date using [*setFullYear*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.40):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(year, month, day);
```

Comment: you are right But i need the time in my current code,which i use to cmpare with the current date and time

Comment: So do you need the user to input a time as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
tt=display_c();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id='ct' ></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't liked. You should explain what your code is doing and why it fixes the OP's issue.

Comment: try this code and add edit your code out accordingly as you want

Comment: it get refreshed after every 1000 millisecond